# Will Mir improve multiple-monitor support?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mir

I have two big personal issues with Ubuntu nowadays. One of them is very poor multiple-monitor support compared to Mac or Windows. It's a fact that I am scared every time I connect/disconnect my notebook to any customer's screen, and I pray for it to function correctly.

Do you have any information if Mir will improve Ubuntu's multiple-monitor support?

Answer (score 3):

As per Ubuntu Blueprints for 13.10.

This blueprint is meant to capture the tasks associated with enabling multimonitor support with Mir, targeting the 13.10 xmir release. This would include hotplugging monitors, as well as projectors. The effort should be focused on delivering for the 13.10 desktop experience, however the architecture should support the future inclusion of mobile multi-display.

For complete detail see [Support for Multimonitor](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1310-mir-multimonitor)

<sup>Source:[Support for Multimonitor](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1310-mir-multimonitor)</sup>